# How to recursively list images by exif tag?

Tags: linux, file-management, shell-script, exif

I have a directory full of directories full of images, all with various "keyword" tags. How could I (in a Linux shell) list **all** images containing `keyword1` and/or `keyword2` ?

Comment: On Windows, Linux, MacOS X, BeOS, Plan 9, Minix, Android, IOS, Coffee Machine?

Answer (score 0):

OK, here is what I put together :

```
exiftool -ext .JPG -fast -p '$directory/$filename;$Keywords' -qq -r -m . 2> /dev/null | grep -i '\;.*keyword1\|keyword2\|keyword3' | sed 's/\;.*//'
```

This will produce a clean list of all the filenames containing either of the keywords, of which you can put as many as you want ; You can then feed it to a viewer to construct a gallery / slideshow on the fly, like in this final function :

```
px-image-tag-viewer () {
    TAGS=
    SLIDESHOW_OPS=
    for i in ${*}; do
        [[ ${i} =~ '^[0-9]+$' ]] && SLIDESHOW_OPS="-D${i} --fullscreen" || TAGS+="${i}\|"
    done

    exiftool -ext .JPG -fast -p '$directory/$filename;$Keywords' -qq -r -m . 2> /dev/null | grep -i "\;.*${TAGS: : -2}" | sed 's/\;.*//' > /tmp/imglist.txt 
    feh ${SLIDESHOW_OPS} --auto-zoom --filelist /tmp/imglist.txt
    rm -fv /tmp/imglist.txt
}
```

Get in the directory, and invoke it like this :

```
px-image-tag-viewer holidays sigma horiz 5
```

With the tags separated by spaces, and an optional number of seconds for a slideshow.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve what you need with `exiftool` alone, using its `-if` conditional syntax and the `-p` print output flag like so:

```
exiftool -ext JPG -if '$Keywords =~ /(keyword1|keyword2)/' -p '$directory/$filename' -r .
```

This recursively scans the current directory, using a regular expression match on keywords, printing out their file names.  It's more or less what you have with `grep` and `sed`, but using just `exiftool` alone.  You get more power because the `-if` expression is Perl-like and can do more than just string matching (such as `gt`, `lt` and other Perl operators).

Adjust or remove the `-ext JPG` check as required (it is case-insensitive) for other file formats and likewise adjust the `-p` option to control formatting of output.